# In Outlook how can I recognize when a message comes into Focused or Other inbox?

Tags: outlook, rules

Is there a way to recognize if a message came into Focused or Other inbox? For example, are the messages marked with some specific header that we can read? The reason for that is that I need to create a rule in Outlook which should work with only the messages from the Focused list.